# Broken dependencies when upgrading SLES 11.3 to 11.4

Tags: upgrade, suse, sles, zypper

I'm trying to upgrade SLES 11.3 to 11.4 with **zypper** using the following instructions: https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_deployment/data/sec_update_sle11sp3.html

After launching the following command: **zypper dup --from SLE11-SDK-SP4-Pool**

I get the following 3 problems:

```
Problem: nothing provides yast2 >= 2.17.140 needed by yast2-dns-server-2.17.24-1.2.noarch
Problem: nothing provides yast2 >= 2.17.140 needed by yast2-ca-management-2.17.27-1.1.noarch
Problem: nothing provides product(SUSE_SLE) = 11.4 needed by sle-sdk-release-SDK-11.4-1.55.x86_64

Problem: nothing provides yast2 >= 2.17.140 needed by yast2-dns-server-2.17.24-1.2.noarch
 Solution 1: Following actions will be done:
  deinstallation of yast2-dns-server-2.17.23-0.5.1.noarch
  deinstallation of yast2-dhcp-server-2.17.6-0.4.2.21.noarch
 Solution 2: keep obsolete yast2-dns-server-2.17.23-0.5.1.noarch
 Solution 3: break yast2-dns-server-2.17.24-1.2.noarch by ignoring some of its dependencies
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to additonally specify the **non SDK repo** with your zypper dup like so:

```
zypper dup --from SLE11-SDK-SP4-Pool --from SLES11-SP4-Pool
```

Background:

`Problem: nothing provides product(SUSE_SLE) = 11.4` means the main SLES 11.4 product itself cannot be found. Use a command like `zypper search --details SUSE_SLE` to see which of your repositories may contain the missing package or product.